# I want to find where this function comes from

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
highlightAlertArea(alertarea_id: string, highlightColor: number, highlight: boolean = false): void {
    const search = (level: IndoorModelLevel) => {
        const found = level.alertAreas.find(alertarea => alertarea.id === alertarea_id);
        const color = ( highlight ? highlightColor : 0xff0000);
        if ( found ) {
            found.object.setFloorColor(color);
            // found.object.setVisibleIn3D(flag);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    this.model.levels.some(search);
}
```

I am currently using visual code IDE,
Currently, I understand how the program works, and I am studying by searching for the function with a Ctrl click. But that function is not a control click, so I can't figure out where it is.
Is there a way?

```
found.object.setFloorColor(color);
```

Comment: Where did setFloorColor() come from?

Comment: Please my answer and let me know is that solve your problem or not.

Comment: This IS the function, if you want to see where it it used you can right click it and click "find references".
If you find nothing (because it is used in HTML), you can do a normal search through the project to see if it pops up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code is that, you have to think in different way. First of all, you have find what is `found` variable. From the line

```
const found = level.alertAreas.find(alertarea => alertarea.id === alertarea_id);
```

it is clear that `found` is an object of type `Areas` or `AlertAreas`. And now We have find what is a `level`. From the line  `const search = (level: IndoorModelLevel)` we can see that `level` is an object of IndoorModelLevel. 
So, `setFloorColor` function is in 
**IndoorModelLevel-->alertAreas List Class or Interface type --> setFloorColor (param)**

**Note:** Please check and let me know.

Comment: There is no change. But I found another way. Thank you for your help.